# why * double pointer value is same with * pointer array?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I have a question with double pointer to pointer array.
I couldn't understand why is *double_pointer value same with *pointer_array value.
I thought maybe there's something with this line, 'int **pptr = ptr'.
why isn't it 'int **pptr = &ptr' ?
Please help me..

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){


  // doulble pointer with array.
  int arr[4] = {1,2,3,4};
  int *pt = arr;
  int **ppt = &pt;
  printf("%p, %d\n", *ppt, *pt);
  // The result is different. *ppt != *pt

  // double pointer with pointer array.
  int ptr1[4] = {1,2,3,4};
  int ptr2[4] = {5,6,7,8};
  int ptr3[4] = {9,10,11,12};
  int * ptr[3] = {ptr1, ptr2, ptr3};
  int ** pptr = ptr;
  // Why is it ptr? I thought it should be &ptr.

  printf("%p, %p\n", *pptr, *ptr); 
  // The result is same. *pptr = *ptr
  // Why *pptr is the address of ptr1? It thought should be the address of ptr.


  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Do you know about array to pointer decay?

Comment: @tadman you mean dereferencing and not decay?

Comment: Nope, [decay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay).

Comment: @tadman This situation is called array to pointer decay? I'll search it. Thank you.

Comment: to be clear, you are asking why assigning `ptr` to a variable results in that variable's value being `ptr` , and not being `&ptr` ?   That is how assignment works

Comment: @M.M Oh.. I thought this line (int ** pptr = ptr) is resemble with this line (int **ppt = &pt)... But it is actually resemble with (int *pt = arr) this line? I should think over this more. Thank you.